# How to store 2 value in session?

Tags: angular, session, keycloak

I created angular web that creates user and log in with user's info
and i implemented log in with keycloak
I want to store my accesstoken and username in one place in session storage so that once the user logged out username and accesstoken will be removed. also i want to display logged in user info, is it okay to display username from session storage? and can i store 2 value(accesstoken, username) in session ?

```
  constructor(private keycloakService: KeycloakService) {
  this.username = keycloakService.getUsername();  
  }
```

i tried this this causes Error: User not logged in or user profile was not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to save username and token in session storage.

You can set item in session storage like:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken',data.token);
sessionStorage.setItem('username',data.username);
```

You can get items from session storage by using getItem().

```
sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken');
```

You can remove one items by using removeItem().

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('username');
```

To clear whole storage you can use clear().

```
sessionStorage.clear();
```